# AngularJS ngview and complex active content

Tags: angularjs

I've been experimenting with ngview and angular routing to see if I can create a single page application (SPA) that allows me to swap out different visualation tools while maintaining a common overall app scope.  Are there limitations to what sort of content can be rendered into the ngview ?

I've tried to compose an angular partial web page (view) with an embedded google map, but it will not render.  The angular module angular-gm says it supports the ngview directive, but I can't find any examples of its use with ngview and my attempts have been unsuccessful.

So, in general what are the limitations for the types of content embedded in the partial web page (view) that will not render/activate properly in the ngview ?

And, does anyone have sample code for embedding a google map into an angular partial web page (view) and having it render correctly in the ngview ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation to the content you can place in a view. You are probably limited becuase you don't initialize your javascript component in a directive or after the angular routing.

The simplest solution is probably to place the initialization in your controller, or called in your controller but delayed by a timer (in example) :

```
function controller($scope, $timeout) {
    setTimeout(startGoogleMap(), 0);
}
```

But the nice way to do it is using a directive. You should look at angular ui, they already did a directive for Google Maps.

http://angular-ui.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

Galdo is right about there being no real limitation to the content in a view. However, what you're likely running into is $scope issues. ng-view creates a new child scope. If you're trying to access variables in the parent scope, you need to prepend them with $parent (ex: $parent.myScopedVar) to get them to display in the view.

That said, I also agree with Galdo about a directive being the better approach for this functionality.